# VBA Access Key Underline Not Showing

Tags: vba, alt-key

I'm working on a vba project right now, and am having trouble getting the access keys to display properly. Here is my code:

```
btnCalculate.Text = "&Calculate Total"
btnClear.Text = "Clear &Form"
btnExit.Text = "&Exit"
```

This is done in the properties box on the form design screen of visual studios 2019. My problem is this: on the form design, the underline displays normally. When I run the program, however, the underlines do not display until I hit the alt key. After that they display normally

I have not had this happen before as the access keys on my other projects have displayed fine. They do work, it's just the display that I am having trouble with as my teacher will take off points. If anyone knows how to fix this I'd appreciate the help

Comment: That's a feature of your operating system, not something you code for.

Comment: Ah okay then. Is there a way to turn that feature off?

Comment: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97413-turn-off-underline-access-key-shortcuts-menus-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Thank you very much ^_^

Comment: I think this is better for VBA (Access, Excel): btnCalculate.Caption= "&Calculate Total"
btnClear.Caption = "Clear &Form"
btnExit.Caption = "&Exit". One uses .Caption instead of .Text for form buttons.